# Is it possible to receive input form a textarea and display output in the same textarea afterwards?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming and working on my first small project. Basically, I am getting user text input and want to replace some letters. The problem is to display the output in the same textarea as I am getting the input in, is it even possible? This is what I got so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Plagiat</title>
<meta name="Beskrivelse" content="Et program som kan gøre din tekst 
usynlig for plagiatkontol.">

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function letter_magic()
{
var text = document.getElementById("input_text").value;
var end_text = text.replace(/A/g, "b").replace(/e/g, "o");
document.write(end_text);
}
</script>

<textarea cols="40" rows="10" id="input_text" placeholder="Indsæt 
din tekst... "> </textarea>
<br/>
<button onclick="letter_magic()" id="button1">Start</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.write()` overwrites your entire HTML every time. Do not use.  Learn [DOM manipulations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

Comment: How do you know when to read from the textarea & when to write to it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: `document.getElementById("input_text").value = end_text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of the textarea to the updated value. Your function should look like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function letter_magic()
    {
        var textbox = document.getElementById("input_text");
        var text=textbox.value;
        var end_text = text.replace(/A/g, "b").replace(/e/g, "o");
        textbox.value=end_text;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is very much possible.

All you need to do is trigger the relevant events in JavaScript. For e.g., the below code wouldbe triggered as soon as the value of textarea is changed and the focus shifts to some other element in the DOM.

`<textarea cols="40" rows="10" id="input_text" onChange="modifyInput($event)" placeholder="Indsæt 
din tekst... "> </textarea>`

Then, in your JS code

```
function modifyInput(event){
    var oldValue = event.target.Value;
    var newValue = "I changed this value.";
    document.getElementById("input_text").value = newValue;
}
```